# C# DataGridView CellClick Returning Previous Index on Click

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have the following code:

```
private void dgv_Checks_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  DoThis();

  if (e.RowIndex < 0)
  return;

  if (dgv_Checks.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name == "CopyBalance")
    dgv_Checks.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["CheckAmountColumn"].Value = dgv_Checks.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["AccountBalanceColumn"].Value;


  // ****** THIS IS WHERE I AM HAVING ISSUES ******
  if (e.RowIndex > -1 && dgv_Checks.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "SearchColumn")
  {
    var acctno = dgv_Checks.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["AccountNumberColumn"].Value.ToString().Trim();
    if (acctno.Length == 7)
    {
      var acctname = GetAccountName(acctno);
      if (acctname.Trim().Length > 0)
      {
        dgv_Checks.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["NameColumn"].Value = acctname;
        dgv_Checks.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["AccountBalanceColumn"].Value = GetAccountBalance(acctno);
      }
      else
      {
        AccountSearchScreen(dgv_Checks.CurrentRow);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      AccountSearchScreen(dgv_Checks.CurrentRow);
    }

  }
    dgv_Checks.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["CheckAmountColumn"].Value = dgv_Checks.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["AccountBalanceColumn"].Value;

}
```

When it reaches this line:

`if (e.RowIndex > -1 && dgv_Checks.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "SearchColumn")`

I am getting back the previous cell's index so I am always 1 click behind.  Am I not using the right event? I just want to capture a button click and only that one in the "SearchColumn".

Thanks as usual.

Comment: Looks like you are doing everything right. Does not make sense why you would get the previous cell index.

Comment: Minor thing, but are you getting back the previous click's row and column index, or just the row index?

Comment: @Kendrick - Both are incorrect. It's returning the cell I click on previously. If I click on row[0].cell[0] then row[3].cell[4] it will return row[0].cell[0]

Comment: Does it not fire the event for the first click?  I seem to recall having this happen to me before, but I can't for the life of me remember what caused it/how I fixed it.  I'm trying to jog my memory, but no luck so far...

Comment: First click is fine. Second click mimic the first click and so on

Comment: Hmmm, that's not my recollection of the issue I had.  I thought the first click did nothing, and the second click appeared to fire the first event.  Either way, the only thing I see that possibly varies here from the general way these events are handled is that you aren't databinding once data changes (not that you should in this case).  Maybe try databinding again at the end of your event handler.  This won't make it work, but you'll be able to trace to see if the right row/column values are coming in on each click...

Comment: I think there is no need of **e.RowIndex > -1** condition since you are already doing a return if its less than 0

Comment: What exactly are you doing in **DoThis()**

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, it has nothing to do with the handler code, and something to do with other page events, master pages, validation, etc.  Something is hijacking your request somewhere in the .net framework that causes it to get delayed, but I can't remember where...

Take your gridview and datasource, and put them in a separate file with no master pages or other confounding factors and see if the problem goes away.

If it is now working normally, either add in components from your original page until you can replicate the problem again, or go back to your original page and step through everything it does.  This has happened to me at least twice, and all I can remember is that it's something that seems completely unrelated.

Not only have I provided a fairly useless answer, but I've demonstrated once again why I should really keep a (b)log of this crap...

Comment: I even went as far as commenting out everything on the screen but this even and it still does the same thing. At this point, the only thing in the event is this check... Maybe it works as intended? o.O